# Move layout up while soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

In the given picture you can see that whenever I try to input something in the edit text the soft keyboard covers the submit button which is really frustrating.
so after some research I found that it can be solve by using -
**`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`**
in android menifest.xml file under that activity.
But It is not working for me. Can anyone sove this problem for me.
[before keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SSc6.jpg)
[after keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QFWA.jpg)

**xml code is given below-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quiz App!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="28dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WELCOME!"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Please enter your name"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:textColor="#363A43"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A8089"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnStart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Start"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried implementing `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`. but it did not work.
I would like to know why it didn't work and if there is any alternative to this to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

https://yatmanwong.medium.com/android-how-to-pan-the-page-up-more-25fc5c542a97

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility) in the [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

- Use [`adjustPan`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/style#Resize) instead of [`adjustResize`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/keyboard-input/visibility) bcz it will move the layout instead of resize.

What I also did was adding [`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) to the layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <!-- Your layout here -->

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
```

---

**If these didn't work for you:**

Use [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Your existing layout here -->

</ScrollView>
```

Use custom keyboard methods like [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener):

```
// In your activity or fragment:
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

    // Your code here

});
```

Use custom dialog or bottom sheet like [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment), [`BottomSheetDialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment).